# Access another control in a DataTemplate in code behind

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate containing multiple controls. One of the controls is a button that needs to access the other controls in the datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="optionsCombo" >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Option1" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Option2" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Option3" />
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Name="DoSomethingButton" Margin="10" Click="DoSomethingButton_Click">Do Something</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the code behind for the button click event, if I attempt to access the ComboBox by name like this:

```
private void DoSomethingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem myItem = (ComboBoxItem)optionsCombo.SelectedItem;
}
```

I get an error: "The name 'optionsCombo' does not exist in the current context"

So, how do I access the other controls in the DataTemplate from the button click event?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it like that, because there's no code generation for DataTemplates, i.e. the *optionsCombo* ComboBox does not really exist in the compilation time, hence the error. To manipulate it in the code behind, you need to use VisualTreeHelper, it's well described over the net. Just get the parent Panel of the sender, then find your ComboBox by name, and then cast it to it's proper type. There you have it!